# Error calling method using same data (new data is always generated)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, automation

I have the following problem to be solved, could you help me?

I have two methods in a class.
The first generates a document (calling another class) and stores it in a string.

The second one I want to save this document number for use in other methods and in other classes, in a way that the document is the same generated initially. That is, do not generate a different document!
I'm not getting ... = //

**First Methods in one class (generates document, calling a method of another class):**

```
public class oneClass {
private String cpf;
private String document() {
        if (this.cpf == null) {
            this.cpf = incluiDocumento.cpf(false);
        } else {
        }
        return this.cpf;
    }

    public void one() {
        System.out.println(document());
        System.out.println(document());
        System.out.println(document());
    }

    public void two() {
        System.out.println(document());
    }
}
```

**Second class:**

```
@Test
 public void testDocuments() {
     new oneClass().one();
     new oneClass().two();
 }
```

**Conclusion:**
I can generate my document and store it in a string. However, in the next methods and classes, I can never use the first document ever generated. It will always generate new documents.

**How can I generate a document and store it for use in tests and validate it?**

**Tool:** Selenium Webdriver, Java.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: If you want to reuse the document generated in the first method, save it in a variable inside the class. Then in the second method access it with `this.document`.

Comment: Another option is to provide the created document as a param to the rest of logic like `insertAuth(String cpf)`.

Comment: @marc thank you for returning. 

This is possible, but if I call a third method and other methods always with `this.document` I will have new documents. 

I would like to always have the same document (same variable) in my test ... Do you know?

Comment: @pirho 
I don't understand...
Could you give me an example?

Where or how i create the param?

Comment: Someone could help me?!!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you might use this approach:

```
public class OneClass{    
    private String cpf;
    //...
    public String document() {
        if(this.cpf==null){
            this.cpf = document.cpf(false);
        }
        return this.cpf; 
    }
    //... method one() and two()
}
```

The document is created only once and saved in a class variable. Any call after that will return the saved document.

So the **Second Method** will always get the first document generated.

Edit:

And test it like in the following:

```java
@Test
public void testDocuments() {
     OneClass oneClass = new OneClass();
     oneClass.one();
     oneClass.two();
}
```

I changed the name of your class from `oneClass` to `OneClass` because in Java  class names start with capital letter.

Comment: It didn't work ... = //

It runs correctly, but after my @Test, it generates a document for each method ...

`@Test
    public void testSameDocument() {
        new testOne;
        new testTwo;
    }`

The second method (testTwo) creates a new document... =//

Could you help me?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, @marc !

Updated question!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @EstevaoFPM I updated my answer, please consider to upvote ;)

Comment: @EstevaoFPM if the question is answered, please accept the answer.

Comment: Now yes!!!!!!   Success!! Thank you so much for the support !! It helped a lot!!! Problem solved!!!

Comment: @EstevaoFPM Cool! Then please accept my answer so that the question is officially solved.